# Better way than using multiple if's in java 8

Tags: lambda, java-8

Is there a more efficient way of writing code than using multiple if's here?

```
 if (fields.getNumber() == 100) {
        for (Sub subfield : xmlSubfield) {

            if (subfield.getCode().equals("a")) {
                author.append(subfield.getValue());
            }
            if (subfield.getCode().equals("b")) {
                author.append(" ").append(subfield.getValue());
            }
            if (subfield.getCode().equals("c")) {
                author.append(" ").append(subfield.getValue());
            }
        }

    } else if (fields.getNumber() == 110) {

        for (Sub subfield : xmlSubfield) {

            if (subfield.getCode().equals("a")) {
                author.append(" ").append(subfield.getValue());
            }
            if (subfield.getCode().equals("b")) {
                author.append(" ").append(" ").append(subfield.getValue());
            }
        }
    } else if (fields.getNumber() == 111) {

        for (Sub subfield : xmlSubfield) {
        if (subfield.getCode().equals("a")) {
            author.append(" ").append(subfield.getValue());
        }
                 }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, **Switch is faster than multiple if's.** I have tried this thing. Once on the coding platform, I coded in both ways and time taken by switch statement was less. In your code, you can use Switch instead of multiple if's whenever you are matching it with either 'a' or any other character. If you want me to change the code, let me know.

Some Code Snippet:

```
switch(fields.getNumber())
    {
      case 100:
        {
            for(Sub subfield: xmlSubfield)
            {
                switch(subfield.getCode())
                {
                    case 'a':
                        //Statement
                        break;
                    case 'b':
                        //statement
                        break;
                    case 'c':
                        //statement
                        break;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
      case 110:
      {
          //Same as above.
      }
      case 111:
      {
          //Same
      }
      default:
           //If you want to print anything if none of the condition matches.

   }
```

You can also refer this article on GeeksForGeeks. [Link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/switch-vs-else/)

Comment: thanks , it would be great if you can provide the implementation

Comment: @Neethu Ma'am, I have shared some code snippet with respect to your code. You can change your code accordingly.